# I keep getting "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool" when trying to login with a user which I already registered

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've been following an article on a website, trying to create a login in page and connect it to a database I've created in MySQL. I followed the article fairly well and tweaked it where I needed to, but I keep getting the same message error as above when I try to login with a user I registered.

I checked the code on the website I was referencing from over and over to see if I misspelled anything but there were no errors. I equally searched and found similar problems but still couldn't find the solution to mine.
Here is the link to the website I was following if it's needed. (https://dzone.com/articles/ceate-a-login-system-using-html-php-and-mysql)
I'm still a beginner in php and MySQL so I may be missing something. any help is appreciated.
Here is the code for the server side of the login.

```
$error = '';
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submitlog'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    //validate if username is empty
    if (empty($username)) {
      $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter username.</p>';
    }

    //validate if password is empty
    if (empty($password)) {
      $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your password.</p>';
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
      if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?")) {
        $query->bind_param('s', $username);
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetch();
        if ($row) {
          if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION["user"] = $row;

            //redirect the user to welcome page
            header("location: ./department1.php");
            exit;
          } else {
            $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
          }
        } else {
          $error .= '<p class="error">No User exist with that username.</p>';
        }
      }
      $query->close();
    }
    //close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
  }
```

my php points at the following line of code that with the problem

```
if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
```

please let me know if any other script is needed and I will provide it. I don't want to populate the whole place with all the other scripts.

Comment: As the error says `$row` is a boolean. It doesn't hold the data you fetched from the database.

Comment: [mysqli_stmt::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns the values into the variables you bound with [bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), then returns a boolean.